# Write a pandas data frame to HDF5

Tags: python, hadoop, pandas, dataframe

I'm processing large number of files in python and need to write the output (one dataframe for each input file) in `HDF5` directly.
I am wondering what is the best way to write `pandas` data frame from my script to `HDF5` directly in a fast way? I am not sure if any python module like hdf5, hadoopy can do this. Any help in this regard will be appreciate.

Comment: http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2016/02/22/dask-distributed-part-2

Comment: Nickil suggested an edit to change HDFS to HDF5 (and then answered based on this), but both HDFS and HDF5 seems to make sense in the context of your question... which did you mean?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to give you a good answer to this rather generic question.

It's not clear how are you going to use (read) your HDF5 files - do you want to select data conditionally (using `where` parameter)?

fir of all you need to open a store object:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('/path/to/filename.h5')
```

now you can write (or append) to the store (i'm using here `blosc` compression - it's pretty fast and efficient), beside that i will use `data_columns` parameter in order to specify the columns that must be indexed (so you can use these columns in the `where` parameter later when you will read your HDF5 file):

```
for f in files:
    #read or process each file in/into a separate `df`
    store.append('df_identifier_AKA_key', df, data_columns=[list_of_indexed_cols], complevel=5, complib='blosc')

store.close()
```